# Common block and subroutine argument

Tags: variables, fortran, subroutine, fortran-common-block

If I have a variable called `var` which is in a common block named `myCB` may I use the same name to pass an argument between two other subroutines which are not using the common block `myCB`?

The code is like below.

```
Subroutine SR1(Var)
      !something here using Var
end Subroutine SR1

Subroutine SR2()
....
      Call SR1(B)
....
end Subroutine SR2

Subroutine SR3()
common \myCB\ Var
... 
  ! something using the other Var shared with SR4
......
end Subroutine SR3

Subroutine SR4()
common \myCB\ Var
....
... ! something using the other Var shared with SR3
....
end Subroutine SR4
```

I do have problem with `Var` passing between `SR1` and `SR2`, could the problem come from the other named `Var` in the common block ?

Comment: I think you'll need to give a more complete example (see [mcve]), and show why you think there is a problem.  As the question stands now, we'll largely have to guess.  There are important things around scope, but there's so much missing from the current code fragment that it's impossible to tell.

Comment: the entire code is 2600 lines, but I will think how to edit my post to be more specific with more details from code, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the legacy code base too much, I suggest you put the `common` block in a `module` and import the variables when access is required:

```
module myCB_mod
    common /myCB/ var, var2, var3
    save ! This is not necessary in Fortran 2008+
end module myCB_mod

subroutine SR2()
    use myCB_mod
    !.......
    call SR1(B)
    !.....
end subroutine SR2

subroutine SR3()
    use myCB_mod
    !.......
end subroutine SR3

subroutine SR4()
    use myCB_mod
    !.....
end subroutine SR4
```

or better yet, I suggest you avoid `common` blocks altogether (this requires a full rewrite of the legacy code base) and confine all your subroutines inside a `module`

```
module myCB
    implicit none
    real var, var2, var3
    save ! This is not necessary in Fortran 2008+
end module myCB

module mySubs
    use myCB
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine SR2()
            !.......
            call SR1(B)
            !.....
    end subroutine SR2

    subroutine SR3()
            !.......
    end subroutine SR3

    subroutine SR4()
            !.....
    end subroutine SR4
end module
```

Lastly, do the variables in your `common` block require initialization? If so, this introduces even further complications involving `data` statements or even the `block data` construct.